# Why admin users don't show up in "Users and Groups"

Tags: terminal, user-account, accounts, administrator

When I tried to reset my password, through the terminal in recovery mode, I saw two other users:
[image]

But looking at Users and groups in system preferences, I only see one account:
[image]

I tried deleting applesetup.done and I got through setup but these accounts were still there
How can I get rid of these other users?

Comment: Screenshots usually work better than pictures of the screen (at least for the second picture). Anyway: do the user names in the first picture ring a bell or are they totally unknwon to you? Do you have currently (or had in the past) several drives to boot from?

Comment: Ive only every had one boot drive